# How does iOS7 understands Swift Code? Is there any Swift support by OS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, swift2

Here is my short assumption on that currently looking more on it.

Application with Swift code bundles Swift specific standard libs with Swift, Apple has changed how standard libraries are shipped. With Objective-C, all of the standard libraries, system frameworks, and the runtime itself, were shipped with the OS. But With Swift, Apple trying to ship a specific version of the standard library with your app.

Please share your thought on that.

Comment: `Apple trying to ship a specific version of the standard library with your app.`  I think so. Look at the ipa package, you can see a Swift Support folder which contains all swift's dylib. And they do the same for tvOs

Comment: Yes that's called `Swift runtime library` found something

Comment: @hereAll Down votes warm welcome but also comment the reason as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Found Interesting - [Compatibility Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2)

According to that - In fact, you can target back to `OS X Mavericks` or `iOS 7` with that same app. This is possible because Xcode embeds a small Swift runtime library within your app’s bundle. Because the library is embedded, your app uses a consistent version of Swift that runs on past, present, and future OS releases.

Any other discussion warm welcome!